# flutter: rotate screen to landscape with new and not with previous screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, orientation, transition, landscape

I want to move from my portrait menu to a landscape detail page. I use the following for it, what works fine with another transition (from an intro to a detail page).

```dart
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
```

Now, in this case, I receive an error

```dart
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 165 pixels on the bottom.
```

That is because the menu page is too long for landscape and without a scroller. I could do workarounds, but is there a simple, clean way to clear the page, turn the page and then to render the new content? Also with my working transition it looks crappy when the portrait content is rotated to landscape or if - worse - the new screen jumps back into portrait for milliseconds before returning to landscape.

I have placed the above code in the initState as well as behind Widget build() (two attempts, not simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I follow, if you are using same page as main page, no matter how you call it it will be "too big" for landscape mode.

Solution #0 - make sure that setState is able to do it's thing. It will automatically render page again.

Solution #1 - simply add scroll capability to the menu page (either with SingleChildScrollView or ListView)

Solution #2 - overcomplicated but if your case requestes it... call next page, pass parameter that you will use to set proper orientation, swtich in init before rendering.

Comment: These are 2 pages. I have the landscape orientation set within init on the called page. Even if I add a scroll capability (that is one of the workarounds I already thought of) this leaves me with an ugly transition (frequently the screen changes multiple times its orientation before final rendering, and items designed for landscape look crappy in the transition from portrait and vice versa). That is why I am looking for a way to clear the page first, then to turn it and then to render the new screen.

Comment: ok you will need to give us a bit more code to better understand context of what is not working well...

if you are transitioning to the page completely with i.e.
```
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TestX()),
                );
```

and in target page in init you have

```
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
    super.initState();
  }

```

with new Scaffold everything is cleared